# Samba share doesn't have write permissions

Tags: windows-7, samba, network-share

alright, I've got one that should be really simple.

I want a wide open smb share for my Windows 7 machine.  Everyone should be able to access it, regardless of domain or username or anything.

My smb.conf has:

> security = share
>   guest account = nobody

Along with:

> [DC_Backup]
>           path = /Windows_Backups/DC
>           comment = Backup of Domain Controller
>           force user = nobody
>           guest ok = yes
>           public = yes
>           read only = no

I can access it, but I cannot write to it.  Windows keeps telling me I "need permission to perform this action"

Where do I start?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On the Samba server, you need to ensure that the `nobody` user has write permissions to /Windows_Backups/DC. You're forcing everyone to be impersonated by the `nobody` account, so that account will need file-level permissions on that share directory. Samba will respect local permissions when figuring out who can write where, in this case it is somewhat like Windows.

Comment: I love ServerFault, it took a whole 6 minutes to fix my problem.  Thank you sysadmin1138 :)

Comment: @blsub6 We live to share what we know.